# Can you make some photos private on Instagram?

Tags: instagram

There's a profile on Instagram where I can't see some of the persons pictures, but from my friends profile I can see them all.  The Instagram is not private. Can you do so on lyrics some people can view a specific picture?

Comment: How do you know that account is not private? Are you and your friend both not following the account?

Answer (score 1):

No, as of now this feature is not available. You can only set your account as private not individual pictures.

See my [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/102262/87130) on other question for more details.